# Returning different statuscode in cXML must I also send HTTP Statuscode back?

Tags: java, cxml

In CXML if the Sender credentials was not correct then in my cxml I send this as a response back to the sender of the cXML post:

```
<Status code="401" text="Unauthorized ">Credentials provided in the Request (the Sender element) were not recognized by the server.</Status>
```

According to cXML this is correct. But do I also need to change my HTTP statuscode to 401 or will 200 OK suffice?

Comment: Who is the client (receiver) and are they also expecting a `<Status>` response for the success case?

Comment: @selbie yes they do, it is a customer who sents an order throug cxml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As It is mentioned in the [cxml User Guide](http://xml.cxml.org/current/cXMLUsersGuide.pdf) cxml error handling is on top of http (transport layer) error message, you can see them as functional errors so you still reply with an HTTP 200

> 3.1.9.1 Status
>
> Because cXML is layered above HTTP in most cases, many errors (such as
>   HTTP 404/Not Found) are handled by the transport. All transport errors
>   should be treated as transient and the client should retry, as if a
>   cXML 500 range status code had been received. All HTTP replies that
>   don’t include valid cXML content, including HTTP 404/Not found and
>   HTTP 500/Internal Server Error status codes, are considered transport
>   errors. Other common transport problems include timeouts, TCP errors
>   (such as “connection refused”), and DNS errors (such as “host
>   unknown”). Validation errors in parsing a Request document would
>   normally result in a cXML permanent error in the 400 range, preferably
>   406/Not Acceptable.

In your case, you want to reply with

- HTTP 200 / OK answer
- cXML 401 / Unauthorized